# Regular Expression replacing keyword that occurred multiple times

Tags: regex

I tried to match the "text" word so that i can replace and highlight the "text" word, using..

```
strText = "this is some triple text text texting word"
Keyword = " text "
Regex.Replace(strText, Keyword, m=> String.Format(" <span class='keywordHighlight'>{0}</span> ");
```

The result is : this is some triple text text texting word

But only the first word highlighted, i need the space at the begin and end of the "text" keyword to avoid matching "texting",

Anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundaries:

```
Regex.Replace(@"\b"+strText+"\b" ...);
```

`\b` is a word boundary in regex. It will only match `text` and not `texting`